# Como destruir una session iniciada en php

Tags: php

Cuál es la forma mas fácil de destruir una `Sesión`, la cual aunque retrocedan en el navegador no les permita entrar luego de haber dado en salir.

Este es el código que tengo para verificar la sesión iniciada:

```
<?php
    include("conexion.php");
    //Variables que recoge lo ingresado x el usuario
    $tab_usu = $_POST["for_nom"];
    $tab_cla = $_POST["for_cla"];
    //Verifica si los campo estan vacios y lo devuelve
    if(empty($tab_usu) || empty($tab_cla)){
        echo"<script>alert('Debe Llenar los campos vacios');window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
    }
    //Consulta Busqueda de un usuario
    $bus_usu = "select apodo_usuario,nombres,apellidos,clave,correo_usuario,correo_recuperacion from usuario where clave='".$tab_cla."' and apodo_usuario='".$tab_usu."' || correo_usuario='".$tab_usu."'";

    //Verifica si el usuario existe
    if($search = mysqli_query($conexion,$bus_usu)){
        $row = mysqli_num_rows($search);
        if($row >= 1){
            //Ciclo que recorre la variable de la consulta
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search)){
                //Verifica si se loguea con su apodo_usuario
                if($row["apodo_usuario"] == $tab_usu and $row["clave"] == $tab_cla){
                    session_start();
                    $bus_usu = "select concat(nombres,apellidos) from usuario where clave='".$tab_cla."' and apodo_usuario='".$tab_usu."'";
                        $_SESSION["apodo_usuario"] = $tab_usu;
                    echo"<script>alert('Bienvenido $_SESSION[nombres]');window.location.href='index.html';</script>";
                }
                //Verifica si se loguea con su correo_usuario
                else if($row["correo_usuario"] == $tab_usu and $row["clave"] == $tab_cla){
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION["correo_usuario"] = $tab_usu;
                    echo"<script>alert('Bienvenido $_SESSION[correo_usuario]');window.location.href='index.html';</script>";
                }
                //Verifica si al querer ingresar digita erroneamente usuario o contraseña
                else{

                }
            }   
        }
        else{
            echo"<script>alert('Error en los datos ingresados');window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
        }
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Usar , `session_destroy();`

Comment: mm pero como se usaria xq ya la he probado y doy clic en regresar y vuelve y entra al menu principal y quiero evitar eso

Comment: yo se aprte de session_destroy este tambien session_unset

Answer (score 1):

`session_destroy()`

Ya solo es cuestión de ver cómo ejecutarás la función, y ya con eso la sesión del usuario dejará de existir.

Comment: mm dame un ejemplo de como seria

Answer (score 1):

> Primero la función [**`session_start()`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) debe ser ejecutada **una sola
>   vez al principio del todo de tu código PHP.**

Quedando así:

```
<?php
session_start(); //Aquí y solo una vez!
include("conexion.php");
    //Variables que recoge lo ingresado x el usuario
    $tab_usu = $_POST["for_nom"];
    $tab_cla = $_POST["for_cla"];
    //Verifica si los campo estan vacios y lo devuelve
    if(empty($tab_usu) || empty($tab_cla)){
        echo"<script>alert('Debe Llenar los campos vacios');window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
    }
    //Consulta Busqueda de un usuario
    $bus_usu = "select apodo_usuario,nombres,apellidos,clave,correo_usuario,correo_recuperacion from usuario where clave='".$tab_cla."' and apodo_usuario='".$tab_usu."' || correo_usuario='".$tab_usu."'";

    //Verifica si el usuario existe
    if($search = mysqli_query($conexion,$bus_usu)){
        $row = mysqli_num_rows($search);
        if($row >= 1){
            //Ciclo que recorre la variable de la consulta
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search)){
                //Verifica si se loguea con su apodo_usuario
                if($row["apodo_usuario"] == $tab_usu and $row["clave"] == $tab_cla){

                    $bus_usu = "select concat(nombres,apellidos) from usuario where clave='".$tab_cla."' and apodo_usuario='".$tab_usu."'";
                        $_SESSION["apodo_usuario"] = $tab_usu;
                    echo"<script>alert('Bienvenido $_SESSION[nombres]');window.location.href='index.html';</script>";
                }
                //Verifica si se loguea con su correo_usuario
                else if($row["correo_usuario"] == $tab_usu and $row["clave"] == $tab_cla){

                    $_SESSION["correo_usuario"] = $tab_usu;
                    echo"<script>alert('Bienvenido $_SESSION[correo_usuario]');window.location.href='index.html';</script>";
                }
                //Verifica si al querer ingresar digita erroneamente usuario o contraseña
                else{

                }
            }   
        }
        else{
            echo"<script>alert('Error en los datos ingresados');window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
        }
    }   
?>
```

> Como bien se te ha dicho en los comentarios debes usar
>   [**`session_destroy()`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-destroy.php).

Para asegurarte de que la función **`session_destroy()`** se está ejecutando correctamente usa este pequeño **script PHP**;

```
if (session_destroy()) {
    echo "Sesión destruida correctamente";
} else {
    echo "Error al destruir la sesión";
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Para el caso que, se cierre la pestaña. Puedes hacerlo con ***javascript***  la destruya si esta iniciada te dejo un ejemplo:

> En el javascript

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
  $.post(Ruta donde esta el archivo con el método de borrado de la session);
});
```

> En el php

```
        session_start();
        session_unset();
```

Answer (score 0):

lo mejor q puedes hacer para destruir una sesion php es iniciarla y luego destruirla, algo asi:

```
session_start(); // este por si no la has iniciado en la pagina que planeas destruirla, de lo contrario no te destruirá nada
session_destroy();
session_unset();
```

con esto deberia estar controlada toda la session.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función de PHP **session_destroy()**

Esta función destruye la sesión, si necesitas saber mas de ella, te dejaré los siguientes enlaces:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-destroy.php
http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/session_destroy-443334/
https://cursoprogramador.wordpress.com/tag/session_destroy/

Comment: Siguiendo esta opción, puedes comprobar el tiempo desde que la sesion fue iniciada con la función ´($_SESSION["timeout"]´ comprbando que no sea mayor a un tiempo establecido.

Te puede ayudar

Comment: siguiendo el comentario anterior puedes comprobar el tiempo de inactivaidad y comprobarlo con un tiempo establecido, se es verdadero se destruye la sesion

Answer (score 0):

lo recomendado para manejar una sesion es lo siguiente paso a paso:
DEclaramos algunas constantes que usaremos

```
if (!defined('SES_COMPANY')) {
    define('SES_COMPANY', 'tusesion');
}

if (!defined('SES_TIMEOUT')){
    define('SES_TIMEOUT'        ,time() + 28800); # 8 Horas
}
```

Verificar si existe y establecer el nombre:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { session_name(SES_COMPANY); }
```

verificar si si existe nuevamente e iniciar la sesion

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
```

verificar si existe e indicar el tiempo de duracion

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['Ses_TimeOut'])){
    $_SESSION['Ses_TimeOut'] = SES_TIMEOUT;
}
```

Una vez Contruida de esta forma tu Session puedes destruirla de la siguiente manera:
Verificas si existe y verificas si el tiempo caduco.

```
function Ses_TimeOutDest(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['Ses_TimeOut'])){
        if ($_SESSION['Ses_TimeOut']  < time()) {
            session_destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo pon un button que te lleve a otra pagina, puede ser que se llame **`cerrar.php`** y en esa pagina pones lo siguiente:

```
<?php

session_start();
session_destroy();

header("location:../");
?>
```

Finalmente pones un *header* que te devuelva a tu index.